# Applets under Java and C#

Tags: java, c#, jar, applet

I have developed an applet under Java and I have to use it on a C# software which I have developed as well. Both of them on my localhost. When I run the C# software I receive an error from the Java Console which states:

> CacheEntry[http://localhost:3624/web/xercesImpl.jar]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970,length=1367760
>
> CacheEntry[http://localhost:3624/web/paqApplet/PruebaPalabra.class]: updateAvailable=false,lastModified=Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970,length=17684

The code which I use to call the applet is this one:

```
<applet code="paqApplet/PruebaArrastrar.class" width="100%" height="100%">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="literalParametros"></asp:Literal>
</applet>
```

Why do I get this error?. I have placed all *.class* and *.jar* files in the same folder. Could you please help me solve this?

Comment: An applet executes within a webbrowser. An C# program executes somewhere else. Could you please elaborate what you mean by "use it on a C# software"?

Comment: Additionally, the "error" you posted seems to simply be a log output of some cache entry objects. This is not an error.

Comment: This appear from my Java console, so how can I see why I don't see my applet after watching this log?, because I don't know.

Comment: Change `<applet code="paqApplet/PruebaArrastrar.class" width="100%" height="100%">` to `<applet code="paqApplet.PruebaArrastrar" width="600" height="600">`  (changes to all 3 attributes) and report back.